# Redis data would be lost after restrating docker stack

Tags: docker, redis

I am using docker swarm to deploy my web application.
Every time I make some changes, I need to remove my stack and then deploy my application. After deploying the application all the Redis data would be lost.
Is there another way to not lose the Redis data?

My Redis service config:

```
  redis:
  image: redis-image
  command: redis-server --appendonly yes
  environment:
    - ports=6379
  deploy:
    mode: replicated
    replicas: 1
    placement:
      constraints:
        - node.role == manager
    restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
      delay: 3s
    update_config:
      parallelism: 1
      delay: 1s
      failure_action: rollback
  logging:
    driver: json-file
    options:
      max-size: "32k"
      max-file: "10"
  volumes:
    -
        type: volume 
        source: redis_database
        target: /data
```

I also define all of the volumes that we need.

Comment: What is causing redis itself to be redeployed? If only your app has changed, you shouldn't be stopping redis.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid losing data, you could use Redis RDB or AOF persistence. You could refer to this link : https://programmerall.com/article/68211490478/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).